# Android Studio 1.1.0 with SDK Facebook 4.0.0

Tags: android-studio, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm using the Facebook SDK in Android Studio 1.1.0. I've import the Facebook file, but when I run the project the following ERROR message appears:

> Cannot call getBootClasspath() before setTargetInfo() is called.

Also, I've put `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'` in `build.gradle`

I'm new to these languages and SDK so I need help please!
Thanks :)

Comment: You don't need to import the facebook library if you are using Gradle.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to import the facebook library if you are using Gradle.

Please make sure to add it to the build.gradle inside your app module (usually with the name app)

Check you added this in your gradle file

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
}
```

I faced some issues and it worked after couple of tries

Answer (score -1):

Did you add below lines in manifest, along with INTERNET permission ?

```
<meta-data
     android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
     android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

<activity
     android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
     android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
     android:label="@string/app_name" />
```